# How to insert a macro (I made) inside 1000 different excels that don't have this macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a shered folder in perforce where I have many sub-folders and inside of them more then 1000 excel files, I'm running the following code for a specific macro i use (that changed things in wb) .
I also need to apply that macro inside those files. I mean that I want that macro will be available inside every excel file after the code run on the files for re-use in other computer is that possible?

```
     Sub ProcessFiles()



       Dim objFolder As Object
       Dim objFile As Object
       Dim objFSO As Object
       Dim MyPath As String
       Dim myExtension As String
       Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

       Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

       With FldrPicker
            .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub ' < can use Exit Sub instead of GoTo
            MyPath = .SelectedItems(1)
       End With

       Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' <-- add this line
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       Call GetAllFiles(MyPath, objFSO)
       Call GetAllFolders(MyPath, objFSO)

       ' restore default settings
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True

       MsgBox "Complete."

    End Sub


Sub GetAllFiles(ByVal strPath As String, ByRef objFSO As Object)

   Dim objFolder As Object
   Dim objFile As Object

   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
   For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
       DoWork objFile.Path
   Next objFile

End Sub



Sub GetAllFolders(ByVal strFolder As String, ByRef objFSO As Object)

   Dim objFolder As Object
   Dim objSubFolder As Object

   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
   For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
       Call GetAllFiles(objSubFolder.Path, objFSO)
       Call GetAllFolders(objSubFolder.Path, objFSO)
   Next objSubFolder

End Sub


Sub DoWork(strFile As String)

   Dim wb As Workbook

   If Right(strFile, 4) = ".xls" Then
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFile)
       With wb
            'Do your work here
             ......
            .Close True
        End With
    End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx especially on `Adding A Procedure To A Module` section.

Comment: If you are on Windows, see this article https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-AA439B90-F836-4381-97F0-6E4C3F5EE566

Comment: @TomSharpe not so relevant for me, because your solution make my macro relevant for other excels only in my computer! but will not be available in case i would send one of those excels to other computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the above comment, you can put your code in a .bas module file an then import it into each Excel file through VBE.

```
workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import ("mymodule.bas")
```

Be careful your Excel spreadsheets are not password protected!

Comment: I'm not so familiar with bas, how can i put my code inside bas module?

Comment: Under Excel, access to VBE editor (Alt+F11), go to modules, right-click, Insert/Module, copy paste your code, right-click, export file => you'll get your module .bas file exported

Comment: after adding this line i get Run-time error '424' becouse Object required..

Comment: I just chaged to this line and it's works good for me : ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import ("Module2.bas")

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at using an AddIn also, then you can just load the AddIn to make the code available to others, so ProcessFiles would be coded as MyAddIn.ProcessFiles.